# remove apple server app on osx 10.8

Tags: mamp, rack-pow, server-application

I normally develop in ruby and serve my developement site with pow.cx.
For some client work I have to work with php and drupal. I had quite a bit of set up problems and incompatibilities between apache / php / Mamp and my pow server.

I've tried to set things up as mentioned there:
https://github.com/37signals/pow/wiki/Running-Pow-with-Apache

When I leave Mamp on port 888 everything is fine, but when i want to run mamp and pow on port 80 i start to have regular problems.

To try to fix the issue I have installed Apple Server app.
I now regret it.

If i turn websites on in the server app. Server takes over my pow url.
If i turn websites off, i can't access the pow url at all (says i have to turn websites on).

If i remove the Server app completely and restart, i can access Pow again, but Mamp refuse to start apache, saying that it can't resolve the domain name set up by the Server App.

So Is there a way to remove and clean the Server app setup completely?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cleanest way to remove the Apple Server app. But at least I manage to get Mamp work again.

I had ot add an alias in my /etc/hosts files with the current name of my local machine

`127.0.0.1 my-lovely-mac`

and now Mamp Apache is all happy again